# MySQL Log Activation

Tags: linux, mysql

Can anyone tell me how I can turn on logs for MySQL. General and Error. I tryed this and it didnt work. /etc/init.d/mysql start --log /var/log/mysql.log.

--Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add in my.cnf in [mysqld] section

```
log = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
log_error = /var/log/mysql/mysql-err.log
```